# Hp 11 Stream Celeron N4000 Virtual Machine PAE error

Tags: virtualization, oracle

Hp 11 Stream Celeron N4000 Oracle Virtual Machine PAE error.  I found a non-PAE distro called Mini-OS and it works OK without PAE.

I could not imagine that any CPU post Pentium would not have PAE enabled.

Can I force PAE on the Centrum?

I am using this tiny Win 10 laptop for Ham radio and it works fine.   I want to install Allstar and Asterisk and they require a Linux system.

For everything else I am using Linux on 2 PC's.

Answer (score 1):

The only time you need to use PAE with virtualisation is if you are setting up a virtual, 32-bit OS and:

1. you need more than 4GB of memory (RAM) to be allocated for the VM
2. you need to be able to access parts of memory that cannot be used for executable code

In both cases, more than 4GB of RAM needs to be allocated to the VM, meaning at least 5GB needs to be installed on the machine (taking into account the shared memory for video) in order for PAE to be properly enabled within the VM. Googling the types of computers that used the Celeron N4000, most shipped with 2GB and others capped out at 4GB. Unless your machine is one of the rare ones with 8GB (the maximum supported by the N4000), PAE is not going to work.